# Make sure the picture is on the current page

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I try to put the picture at the top of the page, it moves to the next page. What should I do to make the picture at the top of the current page, and will not move to the next page?

I use this code:

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
% normal figure code 
\end{figure*}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Do you have a two-column layout?

Comment: Can you expand your question into a MWE? As it stands, it's not really clear what your situation is. Please provide a complete, compilable example document with only that which is necessary to reproduce the problem. (Package `mwe` may be helpful.)

Comment: @Werner  Yes! I use the IEEE template (IEEEtran.cls).  It's two-column.

Comment: The picture moves to the top of the next page. But I want it in the upper part of the current page. @SeanAllred

Comment: @Sean As suggested in the duplicate, move the code for the figure - that is, the entire `figure*` environment - earlier in your code until it appears at the top of the page you want. That's just how `figure*` works in `two-column` mode.

Comment: @Werner Thank You! But, is this the only way? I did it, but the number of pictures will change. For example, I hope the picture at the lower left corner is Fig.1, and pictures at the top are Fig. 2,3,4. Now, the Fig.2,3,4 are at the top of next page. But if I move the figure* environment to make Fig.2,3,4 at the top of current page, the Fig.1 will change to Fig.4. It's not what I want.

Comment: @Sean: Yes, that's one drawback. To circumvent this you'll have to manually adjust the figure numbers. Place `\setcounter{figure}{3}` just before the `\caption` to mark it as `Figure 4`.